# Adding shortcode to product short description

Tags: customization

I am new to wordpress and finding it quite easy to navigate round. I am stuck though.
I am wanting to add a timer to the product short description when adding a new product to store. 
I have the timer plugin and the shortcode, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this on there or how to get it to work.
This is a countdown timer of days and time. 
Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your shortcode directly to product short description.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/#section-7

Answer (score 0):

1. **Edit the Product**:
   Go to your WordPress admin dashboard. Navigate to "**Products**" and
   select the product you want to edit.
2. **Enable Shortcodes for Product Descriptions**:

By default, WooCommerce doesn't allow shortcodes in product descriptions for security reasons. To enable shortcodes, you can use a simple code snippet.
In your theme's functions.php file (or in a custom plugin or a child theme's functions file), add the following code:

```
// Enable shortcodes in product short descriptions
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'do_shortcode');
```

3. **Edit the Product Short Description:**

After enabling shortcodes, you can edit the product short description for the product you selected in step 1.
In the product editor, you'll find the "Short Description" field. Here, you can add your shortcode.

4. **Save Changes:**

Make sure to save the product changes after adding the shortcode to the short description.